# CKEditor in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ckeditor

I'm trying to instantiate CKEditor in chrome extension but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tools' of undefined

with the object being undefined is `window.parent.CKEDITOR`.

Here's some block of my manifest file where I imported only some of the files of the ckeditor folder:

```
"content_scripts": [
  "css": [
     "bower_components/ckeditor/skins/moono/editor.css"
   ],
   "js": [
     "bower_components/ckeditor/ckeditor.js",
      "bower_components/ckeditor/styles.js",
      "bower_components/ckeditor/lang/en.js"
   ]
]
```

And here's how I instantiate the editor:

```
var options = {
  language: 'en',
  customConfig: '',   //no default config loaded
  toolbar: [
  [ 'Format', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline' ,
    'BulletedList', 'NumberedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Link']
  ],
  enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV,
  on: {
    instanceReady: function() { console.log('ready'); }
  },
  removePlugins: 'elementspath'
}

var instance = CKEDITOR.replace('textarea1', options);
editor =  CKEDITOR.instances[instance.name];
```

Anyone has managed to use CKEDITOR on a chrome extension and wants to share some hint? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CKeditor heavily relies on dynamically loaded scripts via `<script>` element. Those are executed in the context of a web page and thus don't see CKEDITOR object, not in the context of a content script that is executed in an "isolated world". None of the two worlds (webpage & content scripts) can access other's objects/variables directly to ensure security of the privileged environment inside content scripts as those have direct access to some of chrome.* API and can communicate with their background pages giving access to all of the Chrome API.

You can manually hack into CKEditor's source code and copypaste the required resources it tries to load inside, like `lang/en.js`, `styles.js` and others.

Alternatively you can put the entire CKEditor in the context of the web page by injecting its script inside a `<script>` element and declare all necessary files in ["web_accessible_resources"](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) in manifest.json. You won't have direct access to CKEDITOR from your content script though.

Anyway, CKEditor *really* should consider providing a complete js bundle with at least English language (or a user-defined set of languages), styles, etc. Nag the developers.

Comment: Thanks for your help @wOxxOm...since I can choose, I think I'll go for tinymce which so far has not such problems.

Comment: Try [scriptTagContext](https://github.com/Rob--W/chrome-api/tree/master/scriptTagContext). In addition to the readme you might find an existing author's answer here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Dario , can you help me to implement tinymce in to the chrome extinction.

Comment: it's not so different from the normal version; just make sure to include the right file in the proper section of the manifest file. I have: the skin.min.css under content_scripts/css, tinymce.min.js and theme.min.js under content_scripts/js and under content.min.css and  skin.min.css under web_accessible_resources. you also need to set ```tinymce.baseURL = 'bower_components/tinymce'```. once everything is setup it's just standard js you would use in a web application